# Add value in Attributestable without reducing the attributetable

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, table

I am working with the modelbuilder to create a model which can be used by people who do not have a lot of experience with ArcMap.

I have a Shapefile with a huge attributetable. I created a new column for a calculation.
What I want to do is set the value in the newly created column, depending on a value in another column and field to a special value.

This is how it works (simplyfied). The column a is the column I have already. Depending on the value of a field in a, I want to populate a field in column b with a specific value.

```
a    b
1    
2    OHBN
3    OFX
4
5    HGF
5    HGF
2    OHBN
2    OHBN
1
```

I tried already the select tool and the the field calculator, but that recudes my attributes table to the selected columns. I dont want that to happen.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Calculate Field](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000004m000000) to do the work for you.  The attached model adds a new field "b" and calculates that field based on a bit of Python code.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much. whats that what you are writing in the expression? I understand the code in the "Code Block" but not whats written there in "Expression". Shouldnt that be "change(!b) since i want to populate the column b?

Comment: @Stophface The syntax in the expression is used to call the `change()` function you created in the code block. `!a!` specifies that you want to read the row values from field a.

Comment: Ah, I understand. I am very new to programming, sorry :) But I am running into another problem. The fieldis not Nullable, although I ticket the box that it is nullable when adding the field. 
ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
The field is not nullable. [OldFor_Com]
Failed to execute (Calculate Field (5)).

Comment: @Stophface I think you should Accept this Answer to your original Question, and research/ask your new question separately. A search on ' 999999' should get a few hits here.

Comment: @Stophface Make sure the field you are calculating (e.g. b) is a text type field.

Comment: Also try adding an `else` statement such that any value not specified returns `""` (i.e. `None`).

Comment: Solved! thank you so much guys. Your awesome! Made my day :)

Answer (score 1):

you seem to have one to one relationship between the codes in field A and the codes in field B. I suggest that you create a look up table with your pairs of values, then you [join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000064000000) this table to your large feature class. If field A is modified, the change will be automatically taken into account.

1

2 OHBN

3 OFX

5 HGF

Comment: thanks a lot. i will have a look at this.
i was thinking about doing it with an updateCourser. But i never worked with python, but then it seems so useful in arcmap...

Comment: @radouxju how would a look up table be utilized for this problem?

Comment: Yep, wont work in the modelbuilder.

Comment: The look up table contains field b. you can join the table then manipulate the join field as if it was part of the table itself. The users of the model might also select different look up tables as input for the model, which is easier to do than using different code block in the calculate field. I don't understand why it wouldn't work in model builder, but I don't know the remaining of the workflow either, so I cannot tell which is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly different approach to your problem...

Instead of storing the descriptive information in the column 'b', import your shapefile into a file geodatabase and create a [coded value domain](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/tutorials/BGDB_Ex_3_1.htm) with the value (column 'a') and description (column 'b').  This way, the end-user will see a more descriptive information when looking at your data.

Comment: The new values need to be in the shapefile for further processing...