# Select by attributes in feature layer changes original shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I recognized something strange.
Currently I am working with the modelbuilder.
I have a shapefile, "Add a field" use the "Make feature Layer" tool and then "selecet by attributes" to select some attributes. Finally I use the "field calculator" to set in the new created field values for the just selected attributes.

Saving the feature layer through "copy features" it saves only the rows with the selected attributes with all the columns.

BUT

Having a look at the attributetable of my shapefile, which I converted into a feature layer, the performed calculation is in it! It changed my inputfile.

Is that supposed to happen? It is changing the original data - the Inputdata!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is how it works. Creating a layers allows you to point on the feature class and manipulate some behaviours (symbology, selection...) but calculate field will affect the source data. If you don't want to modify your input data when running the calculate field tool, you need to create a temporary copy of your dataset.

Note that calculate field can be reversed if you are working within an edit session, otherwise it is not. Note that in your case you should copy the features before you calculate the fields.

Comment: Alright, I thought I am doing something wrong.
Well, the problem is I am working in the Modelbuilder. I have to do everything through the toolbox. I run into a problem which I cannot solve. See the link. Do you have an idea how to solve that? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103012/add-value-in-attributestable-without-reducing-the-attributetable